# sql if exists simple syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting this syntax error but can't find anything wrong with it when comparing to other examples.

```
if EXISTS (select 1 from City where name = 'Perth')
THEN  Print 'Record exits - Update'
ELSE  Print 'Record doesn''t exist - Insert'
```

I find error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if EXISTS (select
1 from City where name = 'Perth') THEN Print 'Record e' at line 1
```

I get this both on zend cloud and normal phpmyadmin mysql 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't actually a valid MySQL query. It looks like you are trying to mix together SQL with how you want to display output based on the whether the query exists or not. You can use this to return whether or not `Perth` exists in SQL:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM City WHERE name = 'Perth')
```

This will return `1` or `0`, which you can then parse with your server-side scripts. The reason it is giving you a syntax error is because MySQL `IF` statements take the form `IF(condition, <action if true>, <action if false>)`, with no use of `THEN` or `ELSE` (as is common in programming languages). Also, MySQL doesn't have an explicit `PRINT` statement, but you could use `SELECT` to somewhat accomplish what you want above (note that we can remove `EXISTS` as False will be implied if the result returns nothing):

```
SELECT IF(
      (SELECT 1 FROM City WHERE name = 'Perth'),
      (SELECT 'Record exists - update'),
      (SELECT 'Record does not exist - Insert')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 'select' instead of `print` in following way

```
select IF((select 1 from city where name='Perth'),
'Record exits - Update','Record does not exist - Insert');
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9ddd/20). Following shows the use of `IF` in select Statement

```
IF((select 1 from city where name='Perth'),
'Record exits - Update','Record does not exist - Insert');
```

`IF` contains two messages.

First : `'Record exits - Update'` Second : `'Record does not exist - Insert'`

First message is printed if `(select 1 from city where name='Perth')` has some results(equivalent to EXISTS) otherwise you will get second message

Comment: hey just wondering what setup your using as this doesn't work for me even if I change the print statements to select ones

Comment: @Tommy. You are right. My previously told way of using `if` was for `stored procedures`. You can see my edited answer. hope it explains use of `if` in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way: using a grouping function will always return a record. If there are no records to operate on, the result of the group by function will be `NULL`. You could use that as a decision mechanism.

```
postgres=# create table city(name text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=#
postgres=# select COALESCE( max('Record exists - Update'), 'Record doesn''t exist - Insert' ) as state
postgres-#   from city
postgres-#   where name = 'Perth';
             state
-------------------------------
 Record doesn't exist - Insert
(1 row)


postgres=#
postgres=# insert into city values('Perth');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=#
postgres=# select COALESCE( max('Record exists - Update'), 'Record doesn''t exist - Insert' )  as state
postgres-#   from city
postgres-#   where name = 'Perth';
         state
------------------------
 Record exists - Update
(1 row)
```